# Antares yaw maneuver: how many degrees?

Tags: launch, launch-sequence, antares

The Antares rocket begins launch with a very noticeable yaw maneuver that seems to rotate it more than the 1.25 degrees documented for the Saturn V. Am I being misled by perspective? Does anyone know how many degrees they target for the Antares yaw, or even if it is for sure more than 1.25 degrees?

See video below for Antares launch with yaw. Notice how much it shifts away from the tower in those few seconds...